# Unity error "AssertionException: Assertion failure. Value was False" on Android ONLY?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering

I'm working with an [external repo](https://github.com/aras-p/UnityGaussianSplatting) on Unity 2022.3.8 and am running into a repeated log only upon switching target to Android:

> AssertionException: Assertion failure. Value was False Expected: True

[image]

The latter logs show the problem is with rendering and the scene is displayed solid black. If I switch to another target, the issue resolves. Posts with similar errors are not related.

Any suggestions on why this is happening?